# Inconsistency with control location and control appearance

Tags: vb6, controls

I have my "about" form looking like this on my computer (Win7 32 bits) and in the IDE 
[image: This is my "about" windows]

And on at least one PC (under Win7 64 bits), it looks like that :
[image: This is my about on Win7 64 bits]

2 questions about this :

- Why is my OK button not appearing when there is nothing to hide it in my code? How can I solve that? The OK button appears when I click the other button or when I click on its location.
- Why are my buttons and my labels shifted to the right, going out of the form I designed in VB6? There is nothin in my code to change their position.

A bit of information :
My buttons are inside a "Frame" control. This frame control is supposed to be 840 twips (VB6 unit...Why couldn't they use pixel?!) from the left and 525 from top. My labels are not inside anything.

Thank you.

Edit : the only code managing the windows is in the form_load. FraAbout is containing the buttons you see above, FraSplash contains a progressbar. The ZOrder make buttons always appear on top.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
```

On Error Resume Next

```
Timer1.Enabled = False
LblRevision = App.FileDescription

SendMessage pb1.Hwnd, PBM_SETBARCOLOR, 0, ByVal RGB(114, 191, 68)

FraAbout.Visible = False: FraSplash.Visible = False

    Me.ForeColor = 0: Me.DrawStyle = 0: Me.BorderStyle = vbFixedSingle: Me.Refresh

If AppLoaded Then
    FraAbout.Visible = True
Else
    t = 0: pb1.value = pb1.min: FraSplash.Visible = True: Timer1.Enabled = True
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Would you share some code with us please ?

Comment: Well, there is nothing related to these controls in the code actually. I added what's in the Form_Load, but it's not much

Comment: How about the properties of buttons ?

Answer (score 0):

This all came from... my configuration panel. Here is how to fix the problem if you have it. I was at 125, just put it back to 100 :
[image]

Comment: I'm on 150% on my QHD monitor. 200% will be the new "small fonts" in a couple of years, especially on tablets. You have to make your code DPI independent now.

Comment: It's hard to do on a VB6 software ;)